# Importing global namespace in python

Tags: python, namespaces

let's say i have the following files:

a.py

```
glo_var = 0
def func():
    global glo_var
    glo_var = 5
    print "A %d" % (glo_var)
```

b.py

```
from a import *
func()
print "B %d" % (glo_var)
```

If I ran b.py the output is:

```
A 5
B 0
```

My question is, how to import the global namespace so the output will be

```
A 5
B 5
```

I need to call the function in the module a.py from b.py so it will affect the globals.

*I don't want to use regular "import" but to use it this way, "from a import *"*

Comment: Please, do not do this in the real code.  People will hate you.

Comment: The output value for A must be '0' not '5'.

Answer (score 4):

Using `from ... import ...` copies the *references* from the other module. Rebinding the value in the original causes it to have a new reference, breaking the link between `a.glo_var` and `b.glo_var` permanently. Either use a mutable object and mutate it, or reimport `a.glo_var` whenever you need the updated value.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, please explain your solution with the mutable object.

Comment: In a.py use e.g. `glo_var = [0]`. Then just read/write `glo_var[0]` instead of rebinding the name.